# Store different types in ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, processing

I want to store elements in a list, each elements having 4 parameters
I'm trying to create an array list that stores for each element the 4 parameters , which are of different types:

> iD: int
>   x position : float
>   y position : float
>   name : string

I use:

```
ArrayList<String> activList ;
```

But when I use:

```
 activList.add(2, 4.5, 8.9,"Name");
```

I get the error:

" the method add(int,Object) in the type ArrayList is not applicable for the arguments (in, float, float)"

I don't know how to be able to add different types to an ArrayList, is there a way to do it ?

thanks for your help

Comment: you've created an ArrayList of type String, so you should only be adding Strings to this list, in your code you're trying to add an int, float, float, string. I suggest you brush up on how to pass arguments to a method: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html

Comment: And you might also try and find and read some good book on object oriented programming.

Comment: As you see there are some answers. I think the correct solution for you depends on the reason why you want to this. I don't think that it is a good practice to store values of diffrent type in somthing like an ArrayList.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You probably need to create your own class to represent those 4 parameters. Then you can insert instances of that object into the ArrayList:

```
public class MyParameters {
    private int id;
    private float x;
    private float y;
    private String name;

    public MyParameters(int id, float x, float y, String name) {
        // ...
    }

    // + getters, setters
}

// ...

List<MyParameters> myParameters = new ArrayList<>();
myParameters.add(new MyParameters(2, 4.5, 8.9, "Name"));
```

Answer (score 3):

You could define your ArrayList as being of type `<Object>` and put whatever in it, but that's not good practice. Create a simple class with your four fields, getters and setters, and use of ArrayList of that type. That'll be much clearer!

Answer (score 0):

Your usage is incorrect here; `add` doesn't take multiple items to add. What you're looking for instead is this:

```
activList.add(2);
activList.add(4.5);
activList.add(8.9);
activList.add("Name");
```

Of course, this still won't work, because your `ArrayList` holds `String` objects. If what you want is to just hold string representations of various objects, you can achieve that using the many implementations of `toString` in Java:

```
activList.add(Integer.toString(2));
activList.add(Double.toString(4.5));
activList.add(Double.toString(8.9));
activList.add("Name");
```

But if your goal is to associate names with values, you should really just use a class:

```
class YourClass {
  private int id;
  private float xPosition;
  private float yPosition;
  private String name;

  // constructor, getters, setters, etc.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this like this:

```
List<Object> test = new ArrayList<>();
test.add(10);
test.add("Test");
test.add(1.0);
test.add('c')
```

For what you need it'd be good to create a class called for example Storage

```
class Storage{
   int id;
   String name;
   float x;
   float y;
   public Storage(int id, String name, float x, float y){
     this.id = id;
     this.name = name;
     this.x = x;
     this.y = y;
   }
}
```

An create List type of Storage

Answer (score 0):

Create a class that encapsulates the behavior of the "element"

```
public class YourClass
{

    public YourClass() { }

    int id;
    float x;
    float y;
    String name;

}
```

Then you can define a list like so:

```
ArrayList<YourClass> activList = new ArrayList<YourClass>();

YourClass e = new YourClass();
e.id = 2;
e.x = 4.5;
e.y = 8.9;
e.name = "Name";

activList.add(e);
```

It would be better to define the fields as private, and access them via getters/setters.

Answer (score 0):

I am not certain whether this is recommended  or any shortcomings, but you can initialize the ArrayList without any generics.
Then you can add any type of object to the ArrayList

```
ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
al.add(5);
al.add("Naruto Uzumaki");
al.add(25.24);
System.out.println(al)
```

This would give you a output of

```
[5, Naruto Uzumaki, 25.24]
```