# How to store elements with different types of parameters

Tags: java, processing

I want to store elements in a list, each elements having 4 parameters which are of different types (int, float, string). I thought of using an ArrayList but many person advised no to use one. Knowing what's the best way to do this could benefit many people.

What would be the best practice to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Store different types in ArrayList](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31301155/store-different-types-in-arraylist)

Comment: Many people said using an ArrayList wasn't a good way to do this so this question could help others like me to know what's the best way

Comment: It's not the `ArrayList` that's a bad idea, it's storing four separate values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `ArrayList` is fine - but the element type should be something that combines the 4 values. For example:

```
List<Person> people = new ArrayList<>();
...

class Person {
    private final String firstName;
    private final String lastName;
    private final float weightKg;
    private final int somethingElse;

    ...
}
```

That's assuming you really meant what you said about *each* element having 4 parameters (attributes, properties, fields, whatever you want to call them). Encapsulating that set of information in a type makes life a *lot* simpler than the alternatives (e.g. a single list with first name, then last name, then weight, then something else, then the next first name etc).

Comment: thanks for answering ! so I can add an element using people.add("John","Doe", 70, France); right ?

Comment: @MatthiasGrahamSlick: No, you'd need something like `people.add(new Person("John", "Doe", 70.5f, 10))`. You need to build instances of `Person`.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
List<Object> myList=new ArrayList<Object>();
```

it will allow you to add any thing