# Retrieve data from Oracle SQL and display as an Array/List

Tags: java, arrays, list

I have an SQL query which returns 2 data from 2 columns; example, abc  1234. I need to write a java code to get these 2 parameters and return so that feature file can use it to print.

Project files are organized like this:

- File A: Contains SQL query to fetch data **abc** and **1234**
- File B: Contains Java code to return data from File A in List/Array format whichever works!
- File C: is a feature file which calls File B and prints data **abc** and **1234** as a List/Array.

Now the concern:

If i use below code to return as List, It returns only **abc** but not **1234** as its of a different column. I know that i need to use Array here but not sure how to construct my code.

This is my code returning in List format.

```
public static List<Integer> queryDB(String host, String port, String 
serviceName, String username, String password,
String queryName) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");

String query = Queries.getQuery(queryName);

Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
            "jdbc:oracle:thin:" + username + "/" + password + "@" + host + ":" + port + "/" + serviceName);

    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

    ResultSet resultset = stmt.executeQuery(query);

    List<Integer> val = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    while (resultset.next()) {          
        val.add(resultset.getInt(1));

    }


    return val;

   }
```

Basically, all i need to do (I suppose) is to convert above query to return in Array format.

Comment: Can you show the code for your query?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Store different types in ArrayList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31301155/store-different-types-in-arraylist)

Comment: @AlainCruz Query Code: 'String query = "Select * "
              + "from (select ba.account, su.phone_no from billing_account ba, phone su where ba.account_status = 'O' and ba.account = su.phone_account and DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE < (1000) order by DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE)"
        + "where rownum = '1' ";'

Comment: @PM77-1 Thank You; But that question didn't solved my issue.

Comment: Why not?  Can you explain?

Comment: You want to return a List<SomethingWithAnIntAndAString>, not a List<Integer>. Obviously, an Integer can't contain an integer and a string. Only an integer. So create a class, name it with a better name than SomethingWithAnIntAndAString, and return a list of that type. For each row of the result set, get the int, get the string, create an instance of your class, and add it to the list. Java is an OO language. You should understand the principle of classes and objects before using JDBC. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classes.html

Comment: I think the link provided by @PM77-1 very well answers your question or you can convert everything to String and have a `List<String>`.

Comment: Its actually not about storing an integer and string in a List. My problem is, when I use SQL query to get data from 2 columns, multiple data will be fetched from each column. So, Column A has 10 entries and Column B has 10 entries. Now, If I use List<> to return all the data from both the columns, it doesn't work! List only returns 10 data entries from column A. It doesn't read column B. I think I need to use multidimentional (2-dim) Array here! Any idea how i can do that?